# Cannot fetch attributes for custom view

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to build an app to help D&D dungeon masters run a campaign.

That requires, for instance, setting the ability scores of the character a player is using on a campaign.

Given that any character in D&D has six basic ability scores, I figured that coding everything on a `Fragment`, while feasible, would result in a mess of spaghetti code, even if one resorted to data binding and MVVM patterns and other shenanigans.

So I went and tried to build a custom view that handled setting one ability score all by itself.

The problem: I get a NPE crash when trying to parse the attributes for the custom view from the XML layout file.

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19 in com.callisto.kd205e:layout/scores_fragment: Binary XML file line #19 in com.callisto.kd205e:layout/scores_fragment: Error inflating class com.callisto.kd205e.views.scoresetter.ScoreSetterView
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19 in com.callisto.kd205e:layout/scores_fragment: Error inflating class com.callisto.kd205e.views.scoresetter.ScoreSetterView
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:854)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1006)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:126)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:95)
        at com.callisto.kd205e.fragments.scores.ScoresFragment.onCreateView(ScoresFragment.kt:44)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:320)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
        at com.callisto.kd205e.views.scoresetter.ScoreSetterView.initialize(ScoreSetterView.kt:53)
        at com.callisto.kd205e.views.scoresetter.ScoreSetterView.<init>(ScoreSetterView.kt:26)
        ...
```

I've tried to build my custom view following [Matthias Siegmund's guide](https://medium.com/@matthias.c.siegmund/mvvm-architecture-for-custom-views-on-android-b5636cb6be26). I may have made a mistake somewhere trying to implement his suggestions, but I can't see it.

Now, for all ye brave souls who dare to tackle the horror I have concocted, here's the code:

ScoresFragment.kt:

```
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "characterId"

class ScoresFragment : BaseFragment()
{
    private var characterId: Long? = null

    private lateinit var binding: ScoresFragmentBinding

    private lateinit var viewModel: ScoresViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            characterId = it.getLong(ARG_PARAM1)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View?
    {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater,
            R.layout.scores_fragment,
            container,
            false
        )

        val application = requireNotNull(this.activity).application

        val database = Kd205eDatabase.getInstance(application).dao

        val viewModelFactory =
            ScoresViewModelFactory(
                database,
                application
            )

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory)
            .get(ScoresViewModel::class.java)

        binding.scoresViewModel = viewModel

        binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner

        viewModel.track(characterId!!)

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }

    companion object
    {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(characterId: Long) =
            ScoresFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putLong(ARG_PARAM1, characterId)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

scores_fragment.xml (pretty much just a testing layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.callisto.kd205e"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="scoresViewModel"
            type="com.callisto.kd205e.fragments.scores.ScoresViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".fragments.species.ScoresFragment">

        <com.callisto.kd205e.views.scoresetter.ScoreSetterView
            android:id="@+id/scoreSetterStr"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            custom:attribute_name="Strength"
            custom:attribute_base_score="10"
            custom:attribute_bonus="0"
            custom:attribute_icon_id="@drawable/icons8_strength"
            />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

ScoresViewModel.kt:

```
class ScoresViewModel
(
    val database: Kd205eDao,
    application: Application
) : BaseViewModel(application)
{
    private var character = MutableLiveData<Character>()

    fun track(characterId: Long)
    {
        uiScope.launch {
            character.value = setUpCharacterFromDB(characterId)
        }
    }

    private suspend fun setUpCharacterFromDB(characterId: Long): Character?
    {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO)
        {
            val dbCharacter = database.getSingleCharacter(characterId)!!

            val dbRace = database.getSingleRace(dbCharacter.raceId)

            val attributes = database.checkAllAttributes()

            for (attribute in attributes)
            {
                database.insertCharacterScore(
                    DBAbilityScore(characterId, attribute.attributeId, roll4d6MinusLowest())
                )
            }

            val scores = database.getScoresForCharacter(characterId)

            val result = Character(dbCharacter, dbRace, scores)

            result
        }
    }

    private fun roll4d6MinusLowest(): Int
    {
        val rolls = arrayOf((1..6).random(), (1..6).random(), (1..6).random(), (1..6).random())

        return rolls.sum() - rolls.min()!!
    }
}
```

ScoreSetterView.kt:

```
class ScoreSetterView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) :
    CustomConstraintLayout<ScoreSetterState, ScoreSetterModel>(context, attrs)
{
    private var iconId: Int = 0
    private var bonus: Int = 0
    private var baseScore: Int = 0
    private lateinit var attributeName: String

    override lateinit var viewModel: ScoreSetterModel

    init
    {
        initialize(attrs, context)
    }

    private fun initialize(attrs: AttributeSet, context: Context)
    {
        val view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.view_score_setter, this)

        val typedArray = context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            R.styleable.ScoreSetterView,
            0, 0
        )

        try
        {
            // I get the crash right here
            attributeName = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.ScoreSetterView_attribute_name)!!
            baseScore = typedArray.getInteger(R.styleable.ScoreSetterView_attribute_base_score, 0)
            bonus = typedArray.getInteger(R.styleable.ScoreSetterView_attribute_bonus, 0)
            iconId = typedArray.getInteger(R.styleable.ScoreSetterView_attribute_icon_id, 0)

            txtBaseScore.text = baseScore.toString()
            txtBonus.text = bonus.toString()
            txtFinalScore.text = (baseScore + bonus).toString()
            imgAttributeIcon.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(iconId, null))

            viewModel = ScoreSetterModel()

            viewModel.attributeModifier.value = bonus
            viewModel.attributeScore.value = baseScore
            viewModel.attributeName.value = attributeName
        }
        finally
        {
            typedArray.recycle()
        }
    }

    override fun onLifecycleOwnerAttached(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner)
    {
        observeLiveData(lifecycleOwner)
    }

    private fun observeLiveData(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner)
    {
        viewModel.getLabel().observe(lifecycleOwner, Observer {

        })

        viewModel.getScore().observe(lifecycleOwner, Observer {
            txtFinalScore.text = viewModel.getFinalScore().toString()
        })

        viewModel.getModifier().observe(lifecycleOwner, Observer {
            txtFinalScore.text = viewModel.getFinalScore().toString()
        })
    }
}
```

ScoreSetterModel.kt:

```
class ScoreSetterModel: CustomViewModel<ScoreSetterState>
{
    var attributeName = MutableLiveData<String?>()

    var attributeScore = MutableLiveData<Int?>()

    var attributeModifier = MutableLiveData<Int?>()

    var attributeIcon = MutableLiveData<String?>()

    override var state: ScoreSetterState? = null
        get() = ScoreSetterState(
            attributeName.value,
            attributeScore.value,
            attributeModifier.value,
            attributeIcon.value
        )
        set(value) {
            field = value
            restore(value)
        }

    fun getLabel(): LiveData<String?> = attributeName

    fun getScore(): LiveData<Int?> = attributeScore

    fun getModifier(): LiveData<Int?> = attributeModifier

    fun getIcon(): LiveData<String?> = attributeIcon

    fun getFinalScore(): Int {
        return getScore().value!! + getModifier().value!!
    }

    private fun restore(state: ScoreSetterState?)
    {
        attributeName.value = state?.attributeName
        attributeScore.value = state?.attributeValue
        attributeModifier.value = state?.attributeModifier
        attributeIcon.value = state?.attributeIcon
    }
}
```

ScoreSetterState.kt:

```
@Parcelize
data class ScoreSetterState(
    val attributeName: String?,
    val attributeValue: Int?,
    val attributeModifier: Int?,
    val attributeIcon: String?
): CustomViewState
```

CustomConstraintLayout.kt:

```
abstract class CustomConstraintLayout<V: CustomViewState, T: CustomViewModel<V>>
    : ConstraintLayout, CustomView<V, T>
{
    constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : super(context, attributeSet)

    constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attributeSet, defStyleAttr)

    override fun onAttachedToWindow()
    {
        super.onAttachedToWindow()

        val lifeCycleOwner = context as? LifecycleOwner ?: throw LifecycleOwnerNotFoundException()

        onLifecycleOwnerAttached(lifeCycleOwner)
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState() = CustomViewStateWrapper(super.onSaveInstanceState(), viewModel.state)

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(state: Parcelable?)
    {
        if (state is CustomViewStateWrapper)
        {
            viewModel.state = state.state as V

            super.onRestoreInstanceState(state.superState)
        }
    }
}
```

CustomView.kt:

```
interface CustomView<V: CustomViewState, T: CustomViewModel<V>>
{
    val viewModel: T

    fun onLifecycleOwnerAttached(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner)
}
```

CustomViewState.kt:

```
interface CustomViewState: Parcelable
```

CustomViewModel.kt:

```
interface CustomViewModel<T: CustomViewState>
{
    var state: T?
}
```

Comment: In your layout XML, get rid of your `custom` namespace, and use the `app` prefix on all of your custom attributes.

Comment: I tried that at first. I used the 'app' namespace as you say, but it didn't work either :( Still, thanks for the tip.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that you're getting a different error for that, then, possibly on the `iconId` line. You've set a reference value for that attribute in the layout XML – i.e., `@drawable/icons8_strength` – but you're trying to retrieve it with `getInteger()`, which should throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`, IIRC.

Comment: Yes, that's another problem, and one I need to figure out (the question being, how to store a Drawable reference on a LiveData object), but the problem with the attributes not being read is preventing me from working on it. Maybe the attributes are not being picked up because they aren't available at that point of the Fragment lifecycle?

Comment: I just tested what I could of your `ScoreSetterView`, and that's the only other issue. How did you know that that was another problem if yours is crashing before that?

Comment: I was researching how to store the Drawable on a LiveData object prior to stumbling on this problem. Eventually I gave up and figured I'd try to tackle that one once I had gotten the rest of the component up and going.

Comment: OK, well, it will cause an Exception, as is, so I'd recommend removing it for now, so it doesn't cause any confusion with what you're observing. Beyond that, I don't really have anything else specific to suggest. Those attributes are immediately available upon inflation. It's nothing to do with the `Fragment` lifecycle. As I mentioned, aside from the `iconId` issue, the namespace was the only other problem in my tests. You might try cleaning/rebuilding your project after fixing that, and then make sure you're looking at the most recent logs.

Comment: I fail to understand why, but reverting back to `app` and removing the `custom` namespace after commenting out all references to the icon caused the attributes to be parsed.

Now I have a different kind of exception. Related to data binding, it seems: 
`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2`

But now the attributes are being read. I don't really understand what kind of witchcraft was going on here, but now it works. Now I have another, different hoop to jump through. 

Thanks for your support and tips. Maybe that icon thing was complicating things somehow.